# How to make mouse pointer disable on a particular folder while doing Dragdrop operation in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

I want to make mouse pointer disable on some folders based on certain condition while doing Drag drop operation.Please tell me how to do this in WPF as I am unable to show the restrict icon of that mouse pointer while hovering the dropped element.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the **MouseEnter Event Handler** Put this code based on your condition:

```
Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.No;
```